# Problems using tableview and tablecolumns in JavaFX

Tags: java, database, javafx, tableview

I'm working with JavaFX and I want to implement a filter that is accesing data from a database.
The code below  access data from two tables in a database. The data is retrivied and put in 
a tableview, using javaFx. My problem is that the last column from the tableview remains empty.
The code is running well, is working fine but that last column should not be empty. I must say that
data for the last column comes from one table and the data for the others columns come from the other table.

So, why my last column is empty?

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent e) throws SQLException {
    tableFilter.getItems().clear();
     DBMain.createConnection();
        DBMain.setStatement(DBMain.getConnection().createStatement());
        ResultSet results=null;
     CheckBox[] boxes = new CheckBox[]{checkAn1, checkAn2, checkAn3, checkSemestrul1, checkSemestrul2,
             sdd, soo, analiza, algebra, marketing, economie, poo, cibernetica, contabilitate,curs1,curs2,curs3,curs4,curs5,curs6,curs7};

        List<Function<Boolean, String>> clausesConstructor = Arrays.asList(
                b -> b ? "an=1" : null,
                b -> b ? "an=2" : null,
                b -> b ? "an=3" : null,
                b -> b ? "semestru=1" : null,
                b -> b ? "semestru=2" : null,
                b -> b ? "lower(denumire)='structuri de date'": null,
                b -> b ? "lower(denumire)='sisteme de operare'": null,
                b -> b ? "lower(denumire)='analiza'": null,
                b -> b ? "lower(denumire)='algebra'": null,
                b -> b ? "lower(denumire)='marketing'": null,
                b -> b ? "lower(denumire)='economie'": null,
                b -> b ? "lower(denumire)='programare orientata obiect'": null,
                b -> b ? "lower(denumire)='cibernetica'": null,
                b -> b ? "lower(denumire)='contabilitate'": null,
                b -> b ? "numar_curs=1": null,
                b -> b ? "numar_curs=2": null,
                b -> b ? "numar_curs=3": null,
                b -> b ? "numar_curs=4": null,
                b -> b ? "numar_curs=5": null,
                b -> b ? "numar_curs=6": null,
                b -> b ? "numar_curs=7": null



        );

        List<String> list = IntStream.range(0, boxes.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> clausesConstructor.get(i).apply(boxes[i].isSelected()))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());



        results=DBMain.getStatement().executeQuery(list.isEmpty() ? "SELECT * FROM discipline d, curs c " : list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(") AND (", "SELECT * FROM discipline d, curs c WHERE c.id_disciplina=d.id_disciplina AND (", ")")));
        System.out.println(list.isEmpty() ? "SELECT * FROM table" : list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(") AND (", "SELECT * FROM discipline d, curs c WHERE c.id_disciplina=d.id_disciplina AND (", ")")));
        while(results.next()){
            String denumire=results.getString("denumire");
            int an=(results.getInt("an"));
            int semestru=(results.getInt("semestru"));
            int numar_curs=(results.getInt("numar_curs"));


            this.masterData.add(new Disciplina(denumire,an,semestru,numar_curs));

        }
        results.close();
        DBMain.getStatement().close();

                // Initialize the person table


            Denumire.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<Disciplina, String>("denumire"));
            An.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<Disciplina, Integer>("an"));
            Semestru.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<Disciplina, Integer>("semestru"));
            numarCurs.setCellValueFactory(
                    new PropertyValueFactory<Disciplina, Integer>("numar_curs"));

            tableFilter.setItems(masterData);






}
```

[image]

```
@FXML
    private TableView<Disciplina> tableFilter;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Disciplina, String> Denumire;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Disciplina, Integer> An;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Disciplina, Integer> Semestru;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Disciplina, Integer> numarCurs;


public class Disciplina {
    private String denumire;
    private int an;
    private int semestru;
    private int numarCurs;

    public Disciplina(String denumire, int an, int semestru, int nrCurs) {
        this.denumire = denumire;
        this.an = an;
        this.semestru = semestru;
        this.numarCurs = nrCurs;

    }

    public int getNrCurs() {
        return numarCurs;
    }

    public void setNrCurs(int nrCurs) {
        this.numarCurs = nrCurs;
    }

    public String getDenumire() {
        return denumire;
    }

    public void setDenumire(String denumire) {
        this.denumire = denumire;
    }

    public int getAn() {
        return an;
    }

    public void setAn(int an) {
        this.an = an;
    }

    public int getSemestru() {
        return semestru;
    }

    public void setSemestru(int semestru) {
        this.semestru = semestru;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include the code for your `Disciplina` class.  Also, you'll find that Alt-PrintScreen and pasting into Paint are much better tools for making screenshots.

Comment: @VGR I've added the `Disciplina` class.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `"numar_curs"` to your PropertyValueFactory constructor, but your data class (Disciplina) does have have a property with that name.

Pass "nrCurs" instead of "numar_curs" to the PropertyValueFactory, since the Disciplina class has a `getNrCurs` method.

From the [PropertyValueFactory documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html):

> `firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName"));`
>
> In this example, the "firstName" string is used as a reference to an assumed `firstNameProperty()` method in the Person class type (which is the class type of the TableView `items` list). Additionally, this method must return a `Property` instance.…
>
> If no method matching this pattern exists, there is fall-through support for attempting to call get() or is() (that is, `getFirstName()` or `isFirstName()` in the example above).…